# Pandas - Find difference based on two subsequent rows of Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe that captures date when ticket was raised by a customer that is captured in column labelled `date`. If the `ref_column` for the current cell is same as the following cell then I need to find difference of aging based on `date` column current cell and the following cell for the same `cust_id`. if the ref_column is to the same then I need to find difference of `date` and `ref_date` of the same row.

Given below is how my data is:

```
cust_id,date,ref_column,ref_date
101,15/01/19,abc,31/01/19
101,17/01/19,abc,31/01/19
101,19/01/19,xyz,31/01/19
102,15/01/19,abc,31/01/19
102,21/01/19,klm,31/01/19
102,25/01/19,xyz,31/01/19
103,15/01/19,xyz,31/01/19
```

Expected output:

```
cust_id,date,ref_column,ref_date,aging(in days)
101,15/01/19,abc,31/01/19,2
101,17/01/19,abc,31/01/19,14
101,19/01/19,xyz,31/01/19,0
102,15/01/19,abc,31/01/19,16
102,21/01/19,klm,31/01/19,10
102,25/01/19,xyz,31/01/19,0
103,15/01/19,xyz,31/01/19,0
```

`Aging(in days)` is 0 for the last entry for a given `cust_id`

Comment: does the last in group always have `ref_column` value `xyz`?

Comment: @QuangHoang not necessarily. This was just to show a sample of how the data is in the Dataframe. It could be any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
# convert dates to datetime type
# ignore if already are
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['ref_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ref_date'])

# customer group
groups = df.groupby('cust_id')

# where ref_column is the same with the next:
same_ = df['ref_column'].eq(groups['ref_column'].shift(-1))

# update these ones
df['aging'] = np.where(same_, 
                       -groups['date'].diff(-1).dt.days,       # same ref as next row
                       df['ref_date'].sub(df['date']).dt.days) # diff ref than next row

# update last elements in groups:
last_idx = groups['date'].idxmax()
df.loc[last_idx, 'aging'] = 0
```

Output:

```
   cust_id       date ref_column   ref_date  aging
0      101 2019-01-15        abc 2019-01-31    2.0
1      101 2019-01-17        abc 2019-01-31   14.0
2      101 2019-01-19        xyz 2019-01-31    0.0
3      102 2019-01-15        abc 2019-01-31   16.0
4      102 2019-01-21        klm 2019-01-31   10.0
5      102 2019-01-25        xyz 2019-01-31    0.0
6      103 2019-01-15        xyz 2019-01-31    0.0
```